# Alternating page numbers

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

How can I have alternating page numbers in the footer (using fancyhdr) in the form of (left footer) page x of y -nextpage-  (right footer)page x2 of y? I now have

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

But note that on the pages where the chapter starts for some reason the numbering does not apply. I am using the report class

Comment: When a chapter starts, pagestyle `plain` is used. You get to know how to redefine that one in section 7 of the `fancyhdr` manual.

Comment: What is `x2 of y` then? If left page is 10 then x2 is 11?

Answer (score 7):

Something like this? The pagestyle is patched into the `\chapter` command, however, this must be done after `\tableofcontents` has been issued, otherwise, this would be applied there too.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\fancypagestyle{mystyle}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

% Now patch the command
\xpatchcmd{\chapter}{%
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
}{%
  \pagestyle{mystyle}
}{}{}

\chapter{My first chapter}
\blindtext[10]

\end{document}
```